# How to add and run subPackages in Dub?

Tags: d, dub

```
Project/
  dub.sdl/
  source/
  examples/
    test/
      source/
        app.d
      dub.sdl
```

*Project/dub.sdl*

```
...
subpackage "./examples/test"
...
```

*Project/examples/test/dub.sdl*

```
name "test"
targetType "executeable"
```

If I try to execute `dub run test` if get the following error

```
Failed to parse package description for test in Project/examples/test.
Failed to find a package named 'test'.
```

The same happens if I try to execute `dub run :test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the command, you should prefix the subpackage name with the root package name.

```
dub run rootpackagename:test
```

It appears you need to specify `run` (or `build` or some other command) explicitly).

Comment: Huh ... I just ran into this, found my way back to my own answer, and couldn't get it to work...

Answer (score 2):

As of year 2017 with dub version 1.3.0: `<rootpackagename>` is optional. For example, I was testing [jsoniopipe](https://github.com/schveiguy/jsoniopipe) package as following:

```
# Add dependency which is not found on dub's repo:
git clone https://github.com/schveiguy/iopipe ../iopipe
dub add-local ../iopipe
```

dub.sdl file:

```
name "jsoniopipe"
description "JSON parser for iopipe"
authors "Steven Schveighoffer"
copyright "Copyright © 2017, Steven Schveighoffer"
license "boost"
targetType "library"
dependency "iopipe" version="*"
subPackage {
   name "formatjson"
   targetType "executable"
   sourcePaths "examples/formatjson"
   dependency "jsoniopipe" version="*"
}
```

Content of testjson.json

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "authors": [
        "My Name"
    ],
    "description": "My first project",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2017, imadev",
    "license": "Boost"
}
```

Run command:

```
dub run :formatjson -- ./testjson.json
```